# Change the default quantity added by "Add to cart" in PayPal checkout page

Tags: paypal, cart

I have this "Add to cart" PayPal button:

```
<form target="paypal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<div align="center">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="email@host.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="An item to buy">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="per dozen">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="48.00">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
    <input type="image" src="https://www.paypal.com/images/x-click-but22.gif" border="0" name="submit7" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!">
    <img alt="" border="0" width="1" height="1" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif">
    <input type="hidden" name="add" value="1">
</div>
```

It works fine if quantity added is 1:

```
<input type="hidden" name="add" value="1">
```

But it doesn't work if I try to change the default quantity added to 12:

```
<input type="hidden" name="add" value="12">
```

How can I fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try will below code, It will change default quantity to 12:

```
<form target="paypal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<div align="center">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="email@host.com">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="An item to buy">
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="per dozen">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="48.00">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypal.com/images/x-click-but22.gif" border="0" name="submit7" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!">
<img alt="" border="0" width="1" height="1" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif">
<input type="hidden" name="add" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="11">
</div>
```

To know more about PayPal button parameters, check [PayPal documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/)

Comment: Thanks! It works! Before your reply, I tried alternately "add" and then "quantity" variables with various settings, but I never thought that they have to be used together, although I have read all the PayPal documentation about this. It works, thanks!